# Ошибка | IndexError

Tags: python

Выдает **ошибку IndexError**.

```
for i in range(27):
    ch=i
    sys=3
    p=''
    
    while ch>0:
        p=str(ch%sys)+p
        ch//=sys
        a=p
    print(a[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У вас в коде в цикле `for i in range(27):` первым значением `i` является `0`, следовательно в данном цикле `while ch>0:`, где `ch=i`, не будет проходить в цикл, а значит в `print(a[0])` вы пытаетесь напечатать несуществующую переменную. Решение: переопределите переменную `a` за цикл `while` или измените сам цикл `while` так, чтоб она переменная `a` определялась до `print(a[0])`.
2. > list index out of range

Она возникает, когда вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующующему индексу.

Решение: попробуйте изменить код так, чтоб в `print(a[0])` не передовался пустой список, так как в пустом списке нет нулевого индекса. Например, вы можете в цикл`for i in range(27):` изменить так `for i in range(1, 27):`

Answer (score 0):

При *ch = 0* цикл *while* не выполняется, значит не объявляется переменная *a* и тогда её нельзя вывести в строке *print(a[0])*. Можете, например, начинать цикл *for* с единицы.

```
for i in range(1, 27):
    ch=i
    sys=3
    p=''
    
    while ch>0:
        p=str(ch%sys)+p
        ch//=sys
        a=p
    print(a[0])
```